# Openstack API Authentication

Tags: openstack, devstack

Openstack noob here. I have setup an Ubuntu VM with DevStack, and am trying to authenticate with Keystone to obtain a token to be used for subsequent Openstack API calls. The identity endpoint shown on the “API Access” page in Horizon is: `http://<DEVSTACK_IP>/identity`.

When I post the below JSON payload to this endpoint, I get the error `get_version_v3() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth’`.

```
{
    "auth": {
        "identity": {
            "methods": [
                "password"
            ],
            "password": {
                "user": {
                    "name": "admin",
                    "domain": {
                        "name": "Default"
                    },
                    "password": “AdminPassword”
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the Openstack [docs](https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/), I should be hitting `http://<DEVSTACK_IP>/v3/auth/tokens` to obtain a token, but when I hit that endpoint, I get `404 Not Found`.

I'm currently using Postman for testing this, but will eventually be doing programmatically.

Does anybody have any experience with authenticating against the Openstack API that can help?

Comment: After installing Devstack, you should see a file (openrc). You have to source the file and run the OpenStack commands.

Comment: Do I source the file as "stack" user? Which openstack commands do I run after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether you want to do it in a python way, but if you do, here is a way to do it:

```
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session

v3_auth = v3.Password(auth_url=V3_AUTH_URL,
                      username=USERNAME,
                      password=PASSWORD,
                      project_name=PROJECT_NAME,
                      project_domain_name="default",
                      user_domain_name="default")

v3_ses = session.Session(auth=v3_auth)
auth_token = v3_ses.get_token()
```

And you `V3_AUTH_URL` should be `http://<DEVSTACK_IP>:5000/v3` since keystone is using port 5000 as a default.

If you do have a multi-domain devstack, you can change the domains, otherwise, they should be `default`

Just in case you don't have the client library installed: `pip install python-keystoneclient`

Here is a good doc for you to read about it:
https://docs.openstack.org/keystoneauth/latest/using-sessions.html

HTH

Comment: I just did `telnet localhost 5000` on the devstack VM, and nothing is listening on this port. Perhaps the Keystone service is not running? Is there a way I can check?

Comment: it should be running by default if you are using Ubuntu. Try `service keystone status` or `ps -ef | grep keystone` see whether it is running. Maybe the devstack is not installed correctly. Are you be able to log in through the dashboard?

Comment: It seems to be running. I see a master and 2 worker processes running. I am able to login to the dashboard, and create instances, networks and volumes without issue.

Comment: Yeah, if you are able to login to the dashboard, that means your keystone service is up and running. Keystone team is working on changing the auth_url to `/identity` but I believe in the meantime, using the `5000` should work in `v3` and It works for me (just tried).

Comment: Another possibility is that your Devstack is hosted on a private network. I added `HOST_IP` in the `local.conf` when I configured my devstack so I can have public service endpoints for keystone, nova, and etc.

Comment: I got this working with `python-keystoneclient` after changing the HOST_IP in `local.conf`. Thanks for your response!

Comment: glad that this is helpful!